# why (object) NULL or new stdClass IN a php function?

Tags: php, class, object

Who can explain why this returns an error:

```
$test = new myclass();

class myclass {
    private $object = (object) NULL;

    public function addmember() {
        $this->object->member1 = 'member 1';
    }
}
$test -> addmember();
```

... and this is OK:

```
$test = new myclass();

class myclass {
    private $object = '';

    public function addmember() {
        $this->object = (object) NULL;// new stdClass();
        $this->object->member1 = 'member 1';
    }
}
$test -> addmember();
```

But why? Who can explain why the first example is wroing? 
Why I have to put the line with "(object)NULL" IN the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressions are not allowed in a class body definition.

***From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):***

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

For example, you can not do this:

```
<?php
class A {
    public $x = 1 + 2; // < expression
}
?>
```

But can do this:

```
<?php
class A {
    public $x;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->x = 1 + 2;
    }
}
?>
```

Also, you can initialize property within a class body by constant value, that does not need to be evaluated on parse process:

```
<?php
class A {
    public $x = 123; // < constant value
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your example. But why definition expressions are not allowed in a class body?

Comment: @user2753885 , this question should be addressed to developers (Zend).

Comment: @user2753885 - because the developers chose the syntax that doesn't allow that. And that's **the rule**, you can't use definition expression in class body.